# How to install/update javascript vendors in symfony2 project?

Tags: symfony

In my Symfony2 project I have a number of javascript dependencies and it would be nice to have them managed along with php dependencies. Right now I am adding them to the deps file along with php dependencies and create a symlink to the web dir, for example:

```
//deps
[knockout-js]
    git=git://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.git
```

The problem is that javascript libraries (most of them) need to be compiled from several files into one. So after installing/updating vendors, I need to go and run compilation scripts by hand. As far as I know, bin/vendors script does not support pre/post update hooks, which would solve this problem.

Anyways, how do you approach updating of javascript vendors in your projects?

Answer (score 8):

There may be fancier ways... but I just use the paths in my base template like so:

```
{% javascripts
    filter='yui_js'

    '../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tab.js'
    '../vendor/harvesthq/chosen/coffee/lib/select-parser.coffee'
    '../vendor/harvesthq/chosen/coffee/lib/abstract-chosen.coffee'
    '../vendor/harvesthq/chosen/coffee/chosen.jquery.coffee'

    '@SOTBCoreBundle/Resources/public/js/script.js'
%}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Comment: This is not related to my question

Comment: how so? You asked how to include vendor javascript in your project. This is how I do it... assetic handles the compiling of coffee and less files.

Comment: The question is about installing/updating javascript vendor libraries.

Comment: if your libraries are included like this, then they will be updated along with your other libraries. I run the latest version of the `chosen` lib and `bootstrap` without running extra commands or compilation steps. If you have custom commands you want to execute from bin/vendors, just edit bin/vendors. This script is part of your app and not vendor code so there is no problem with editing it to add your own hooks/calls.

Comment: I finally got your point. Assetic can include files from any location, not just from document root.

Answer (score 5):

Composer can be used to manage javascript dependencies as well. By default composer is using only one repository called Packagist which is a repository for PHP libraries only. However, as suggested [here](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/524#issuecomment-4912681), you can add your own repositories for javascript (or any other) libraries.

Here's my composer.json that adds a custom knockout-js repository:

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.2",
        "symfony/symfony": ">=2.0.10,<2.1.0-dev",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.1.0,<2.2.0-dev",
        "twig/extensions": "*",

        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.0.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.0.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.0.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.0.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.0.*",
        "knockout/knockout-js": "2.1.0"
    },

    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Acme": "src/"
        }
    },

    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "knockout/knockout-js",
                "version": "2.1.0",
                "source": {
                    "type": "git",
                    "url": "https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.git",
                    "reference": "v2.1.0"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "knockout/knockout-js",
                "version": "2.0.0",
                "source": {
                    "type": "git",
                    "url": "https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.git",
                    "reference": "v2.0.0"
                }
            }
        }
    ]

}
```

Repository consists of packages (which is combination of source and version of library). Here I have 2 packages (2.1.0, 2.0.0) that already contain pre-built source of knockout.js, so you don't have to compile anything.

Now, there are times when you might want to compile and use latest code. To automate this routine, i figured, one can use git post-checkout hook.
Add a new package that refers to the latest code:

```
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "knockout/knockout-js",
            "version": "master",
            "source": {
                "type": "git",
                "url": "https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.git",
                "reference": "master"
            }
        }
    }
```

Reference this package in require section:

```
"knockout/knockout-js": "master"
```

And a post-checkout hook with build instructions. For knockout.js it is simple:

```
// vendor/knockout/knockout-js/.git/hooks/post-checkout

#!/bin/sh

echo "Building knockout.js";
`cd build && ./build-linux`;
```

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you don't want to use assetic bundle you can setup your deps (composer) to load javascript vendors into some folder under `web` directory.

[This post](http://codophony.blogspot.com/2012/11/symfony2-and-js-vendors.html) describes how to do it using `deps` file. And [this post](http://codophony.blogspot.com/2012/11/symfony2-1-x-and-js-vendors.html) - how to do it via composer.